# "Service disruption" in the context of botnets/malware

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, software

I'm trying to translate service disruption in the context of malware, specifically botnets.

[This paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7380847/) describes what botnets are used for:

> Botnets used for information collection, distributed computing,
>   **service disruption**, fraud, add-on and spreading.

(Emphasis: mine)

Service disruption is explained later on like this:

> Botnets try to make a negative impact on service readiness and
>   continuity

To me it seems pretty clear that the author is talking about denial of service attacks here. But those are mentioned in the following section describing botnet attacks. So I'm looking for a generic term for denial of service attacks.

Right now I'm just translating the second sentence to describe the word service disruption:

> Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um die Verfügbarkeit anderer Dienste
>   negativ zu beeinflussen.

But maybe there's a shorter, more elegant solution to this.

Comment: *Service disruptions* are simply *Betriebsstörungen*. But because those botnets are not *using* service disruptions but rather induce them, you have to place the verb "verursachen" in there. *Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um beim Opfer Betriebsstörungen zu verursachen.*

Comment: Hmm _Betriebsstörungen_ sounds horribly to me, but it seems to be used a lot and captures the meaning pretty well. So maybe it's just me... Feel free to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: *Betriebsstörung* is a word in everyday use. https://www.google.de/search?q=Betriebsst%C3%B6rung&tbm=isch Oh, and it is horrible. Not the word, but …

Comment: Don't worry... if the original uses "readiness" instead of "availability"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Als möglichst kurze Übersetzung schlage ich vor:

> Botnetze werden benutzt, um Dienste zu stören.

Dass die Botnetze andere Dienste, nicht sich selbst, stören wollen, versteht sich von selbst. Das Wort "Verfügbarkeit" ist auch nur eine Aufblähung des Satzes. "Benutzt" schlägt "eingesetzt" nur, wenn die Silben- oder Buchstabenzahl eine Rolle spielt.

Dass die deutsche Sprache Kompositionen begünstigt ermuntert in der Tat zu Konstruktionen wie:

> Botnetze werden zur Dienststörung benutzt.

In der Praxis scheint es mir aber in diesem Fall nicht geläufig. Über den Grund kann ich nur spekulieren. Womöglich drängen sich hier Assoziationen zum öffentlichen Dienst und Bürojobs zu sehr auf. "Betriebsstörung" wäre auch nicht falsch, aber lassen mich an die Welt der Mechanik denken (Aufzüge, Bahnreisen).

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a generic term for denial of service attacks?

Maybe

> - Botnetze verursachen **Serverdienstblockaden**
> - Botnetze lancieren **Überlast[ungs]angriffe** [auf Server] / **Dienstblockadeangriffe**
> - Botnetze realisieren **Überlast[ungs]attacken** [auf Server]

After reading your comments I have other proposals:

> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um den Betrieb von Webseiten zu beeinträchtigen.
> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um den Betrieb von Webseiten zu verunmöglichen.
> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um Webseiten lahmzulegen.
> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um Webseiten in die Knie zu zwingen.

You may replace *»Webseiten«* by *»Webdienste[n]«*.

> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um Webdienste unbrauchbar zu machen.
> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um Webdienste unbenutzbar zu machen.
> - Botnetze werden eingesetzt, um Webdienste unverwendbar zu machen.

Comment: Wer benutzt bitte "Dienstblockadeangriff"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your suggestions sound pretty synonymous to denial of service attacks, I'm not quite sure if they hit the point.

Comment: @Janka: Kommt bei Google auf 217 Einträge.

Comment: Also praktisch gesehen: niemand.

Comment: @Phonolog: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Janka: ... 218.

Comment: Sorry to be so frank, but apart from sounding very sluggish and aritficial (noone with knowledge on the subject would use such words or phrasing), you make up aspects not contained in the original text, in which denial-of-service attacks and web pages are not mentioned at all.

Comment: @jarnbjo: The question states: _»So I'm looking for a generic term for denial of service attacks.«_. And behind the link _This paper_ (tab _Abstract_) you can find: _»... Botnets have been used for many attacks, such as ... distributed denial-of-service ...«_.

Comment: @Pollitzer Exactly, he is asking for a generic term for XYZ, not an artifically constructed and by noone used term for XYZ (Serverdienstblockaden, Überlast[ungs]angriffe, Überlast[ungs]attacken, Dienstblockadeangriffe), nor for one of many potential consequences of XYZ (Betrieb von Webseiten zu beeinträchtigen).

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on fluency in the target language, rather than trying to find a single term that works as a translation of an English term in all contexts.

*DDoS-Angriffe* or *DDoS-Attacken* is perfectly valid Denglisch.  Even just *Angriffe* is arguably clear enough in context of your first example sentence.

Combing https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial_of_Service for inspiration:
*Dienstblockaden* is more precise, *absichtlich herbeigeführte Serverüberlastungen* is too much.

I will also propose *Überlastungsangriffe*, and *Überlastungsangriffe auf Server* or *Überlastungsangriffe auf Dienste*.  No precise English equivalent comes to my mind, but I assume that is a non-goal.